# How to develop a listview with sticky column like Google Calendar

Tags: android, listview, calendar

I am working on an Android app that has the calendar list view as in Google Calendar.

Specifically I want to have the effect where when user scrolls the event list view on the right, the date list on the left will move up when the next day section comes. Please refer to how the Google Calendar works.

I found some libraries that do the effects of sticky header, like Instagram.

For example,

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

https://github.com/DWorkS/AStickyHeader

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders

http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/

However, all of them are actually implementing them like Instagram, i.e. section header runs through entire row, individual items below. It's not like in Google Calendar, left column sticky and right is scrollable.

I couldnt find a way to change the library that I use HeaderListView to effect. The header and list and actually a listview itself. I couldnt split them to left and right to achieve the effect of Google Calendar.

Anyone know if there's any other library that can do like Google Calendar? Or any hint on how can I develop it from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SuperSLiM does what you are looking for:
https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM should do it :)

Comment: I found the same library and modified from there too (Need the extra month header)  :) Thanks for your suggestion.